# execute code in ASP.net MVC after action result has been sent to user

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have an ASP.net MVC controller action which needs to do some code (cleanup, sending emails, ...) in case the action was successful.

I don't want to let the user wait in the meantime. So I am wondering if there is a way to execute code AFTER the action has been executed AND the result has been sent to the browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Tasks, I find them to be easier to use than threads.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.aspx

If you are using something like the entity framework, we use an interface we created called INotifySaving and in our datacontext if the entity we are saving implements INotifySaving  tat we call the OnSaving method. In OnSaving we will often use tasks to run longer running methods. Hope that helps.

Comment: An async controller does not execute after the response is sent.

Comment: thats why i added the tasks library stuff.

Comment: RIGHT, a Task or Thread. Sometimes it's so easy but you just can't come up with the solution. But you should really remove the first link because as Andrew already said asynchronous controllers are rather used for long running requests.

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way is to use [Visual Studio Async](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/gg316360). Currently it is in SP1, but it works well. Task, Thread, Async controller are not good in this problem

Comment: I think the Visual Studio Async CTP would be overkill for just delaying the execution of one function. Task and Thread offers exactly what I need - but thanks for mentioning it.